# How to obtain wordpress root url (ABSPATH changes on each page)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wordpress installed at:

**http://example.com/wordpress/**

When on homepage, the ABSPATH constant outputs exactly that, but when you navigate off to some other page, like:

http://example.com/wordpress/contact

the ABSPATH also turns to:

http://example.com/wordpress/contact

The question is, how can I obtain the actual root (marked in bold) no matter on which page I am - without hard-coding it?

I'm a bit confused with why ABSPATH changes value, aren't constants unchangeable once they are defined?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `Site_url();`... :)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue on an admin page. Not only do you have to avoid the extra folder that gets inserted, WP may be installed in a folder itself.

Here is a way, albeit somewhat convoluted and written for clarity, that makes the adjustments for these various items. It does avoid `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` issues as well:

```
if (!defined(PLUGINUPDATEMGR_DOMAIN)) 
    define("PLUGINUPDATEMGR_DOMAIN", strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) );

$wprootbase = strtolower( site_url() );

$wprootstart = strpos( $wprootbase, PLUGINUPDATEMGR_DOMAIN ) + 
    strlen( PLUGINUPDATEMGR_DOMAIN  ); // + 1 to strip the leading slash/backslash

$wprootend = strlen( $wprootbase );

$wproot = substr( $wprootbase, $wprootstart, $wprootend );

echo "Local WP path = '" . $wproot . '"';
```

Shaken, not stirred, output:

```
Local WP path = '/wp/wordpress-3.4.2"
```

Of course, YMMV =;?)

Answer (score 0):

ABSPATH returns the absolute path to the php file in the server such as /var/www/wordpress/, do check your wordpress install.

The answer to your problem is to use:

> site_url()

or

> bloginfo()

As the people above mentioned.

You could also use

> $var = get_bloginfo('wpurl');

To get the value into a variable

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is

```
<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>
```

---

Here is some text because I must have at least 30 characters

Comment: This question is more than 3 years old and already has an accepted answer. Try to answer more current questions please.

Comment: and this cannot be confused with `get_home_path()` which returns root path such as `/var/www/wordpress/`